# Segmentation faults during doctrine hydration - how to debug?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, uuid

I am running a console command that fetches all entities of one type (and reads some data from them).

```
$q = $this->em->createQuery(/** @lang DQL */'select u from App\Entity\DataSample u order by u.creationDate ASC');
```

Both iteration strategies:

```
foreach ($q->getResult() as $d) {
}
```

and

```
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
foreach ($iterableResult as $onerow) {
    /* @var $d DataSample */
    $d = $onerow[0];

}
```

lead to a segmentation fault!
Note, I am actually doing nothing inside the loop!
The second loop does run for some few tenthousand iterations and segfaults then, the first one segfaults during `getResult()`.
There is also enough memory available, the program breaks at roughly 200 MB memory usage.
My xdebug trace is not really helpful to me, it ends as follows:

```
240.2365  489614864                                     -> str_pad() /var/www/rrr/vendor/ramsey/uuid/src/Codec/StringCodec.php:167
  240.2365  489614904                                   -> Ramsey\Uuid\Builder\DefaultUuidBuilder->build() /var/www/rrr/vendor/ramsey/uuid/src/Codec/StringCodec.php:84
  240.2365  489615000                                     -> Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid->__construct() /var/www/rrr/vendor/ramsey/uuid/src/Builder/DefaultUuidBuilder.php:52
  240.2365  489614448                           -> Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->hydrateColumnInfo() /var/www/rrr/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php:270
  240.2365  489614448                           -> Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidType->convertToPHPValue() /var/www/rrr/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php:315
```

I checked all (ramsey/uuid) ids in the corresponding table, and all return true on `Uuid::isValid()`

**Fun fact:** When outputting all ids, I found out that it always happens at the same DataSample!?

Comment: Not really a way to debug, but try updating PHP to latest bugfix version first - maybe the segfault will go away on its own

Comment: I just apt-get upgraded from 7.1.26 to 7.1.29, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a "solution":

I inserted a call to `$em->clear()` as well as a `gc_collect_cycles` every 100 iterations, now it terminates (and is in fact way faster!).

```
$i = 0;
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
foreach ($iterableResult as $onerow) {
    /* @var $d DataSample */
    $d = $onerow[0];
    if($i % 100 === 0){
        $this->em->clear();
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
    $i++;
}
```

But obviously, this only works for the iterableResult, using `getResult` should theoretically work as well??